# How to programatically create a Facebook application via JS SDK or Open Graph API? (createApplication)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I know there are currently two methods that can be used to do this, documented (poorly) on Facebook's Developer site:

1. [The old (depreciated) JavaScript SDK *FB.Connect.createApplication*](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/oldjavascript/FB.Connect.createApplication)
2. [A new FBJS method *Facebook.createApplication* (only for use on Canvas pages)](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/fbjs/createApplication)

The problem is that I not using a Canvas app that runs FBJS, and I am not using the OLD JS SKD. I am trying to do this on a regular old PHP website that uses the [current JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) and the [PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/).

I am doing the usual Open Graph API calls and such with the current SDK, so I understand the basics, I'm just not sure how to proceed to use the OLD SDK, or if (fingers crossed) I even really have to?

So, is there a way to make new Facebook Apps with the current JS SDK? Or with a server side PHP SDK call to the Graph?

**And if not, how do I call the old SDK to do this?**

Thanks

UPDATE: You still can't do this, but there is an official bug in the Facebook tracker about it: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/295627350461318

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't outside of the OLD SDK as you indicated. It's been removed (what Facebook calls "deprecated"). I put in a feature request recently for them to add it back into the API:

Me:

> The Facebook Developer tool is
> considerably lacking in features. We'd
> like to be able to create a third
> party application that adds layers of
> functionality to the developer
> application, but we'd need to be able
> to create and administer applications
> via the Graph API.
>
> The Graph API supports querying for
> information on existing applications.
> To create, administer or delete
> applications developers must go to the
> Developer Application.

Them:

> ------- Comment #1 From Jeff Bowen 2010-12-07 16:59:12 (-) [reply]
>
> ------- Thanks for the request. We’ll track this on our wishlist

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you have confirmed my suspicions. But I am also looking for guidance on HOW to create apps using the Old API.

Comment: Sorry for leaving this hanging so long - I have given up on figuring out how to do this with the old API obviously - so here is the answer flag! Also, check out the official bug about this here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/295627350461318

Comment: Seems this bug (/bugs/295627350461318) has been fixed, or the interweb gremlins have eaten it.  It no longer exists.