# Is it possible to create a facebook app programatically?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been looking through the documentation regarding facebook's user 'accounts' object, which can be used to tell you all the apps and pages a certain user administrates via a get request.

However, I'm interested in knowing if you can use a POST request to generate an app.  However, making a POST request to '/me/accounts/' in the graph api with the name and category fields being passed in always results in this:

```
{
    error: {
        type: "OAuthException",
        message: "(#152) Invalid Page Category",
    }
}
```

I am unable to find any documentation on valid page categories (having tried pretty much every value I've found in the output from the get-request), and nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question, which describes the process pretty well: [How to programatically create a Facebook application via JS SDK or Open Graph API? (createApplication)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719260/how-to-programatically-create-a-facebook-application-via-js-sdk-or-open-graph-api)