# How can I register a Facebook app on behalf of my users?

Tags: facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to programatically create a Facebook application via JS SDK or Open Graph API? (createApplication)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719260/how-to-programatically-create-a-facebook-application-via-js-sdk-or-open-graph-ap)

I recall that when Disqus launched, it created Facebook Apps automatically for each site you registered with the service (they have names like "DISQUS Comments [jeremiahlee]"). This is quite nice, as it prevents any single bad user's behavior from hurting the edge rank of other users. I have a publishing application that I'd like to do this for. I remember Facebook talked about this feature at a past F8, but I can't find documentation on it now.

Update: I found a reference to the [Create Application API](http://allfacebook.com/facebook-now-making-it-easier-for-applications-to-create-other-apps_b8097), but nothing currently on the Facebook developer site. New [Graph API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/) says, "To create, administer or delete applications developers must go to the App Dashboard." Is the Create Application API still available?

Comment: Also found the post on Facebook's blog < https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2009/10/13/making-it-easier-to-build-with-facebook/ > and Platform News < https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/328/ >, but no references to its discontinuation.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't do that as stated at their documentation.
I looked for it here and it really seems to have been discontinued.